# Problem install scipy on Python 3

Tags: python, raspbian

I am running Linux on Rasbpian and using Python 3.7.3.
I have tried for days to install scipy but unsuccessful.

I have tried pip, pip3, apt-get etc..
I have even tried uninstalling and re-installing numpy but no use.

It produces this error :

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-fc2cutln/scipy/setup.py", line 540, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-fc2cutln/scipy/setup.py", line 516, in setup_package
        from numpy.distutils.core import setup
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-x0_6h9tn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
        from . import add_newdocs
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-x0_6h9tn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
        from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-x0_6h9tn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .type_check import *
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-x0_6h9tn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
        import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-x0_6h9tn/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError:
    Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
    likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
    If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
    files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

    Original error was: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55252264/importerror-libf77blas-so-3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di

You probably just need to install libatlas's development library:

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
```

Then retry:

```
pip install scipy
```